# Significato di "sacche di neve"

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Ferro* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> La facile cresta doveva bene essere facile, anzi elementare, d’estate, ma noi la trovammo in condizioni scomode. La roccia era bagnata sul versante al sole, e coperta di vetrato nero su quello in ombra; fra uno spuntone e l’altro c’erano **sacche di neve** fradicia dove si affondava fino alla cintura.

Ho letto il contenuto della [voce "sacca" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sacca), ma non sono sicura di che cosa significhi "sacche di neve". Semplicemente accumuli di neve? Rientranze del terreno piene di neve?

Ricercando "sacche di neve" su Google se ne trovano parecchie occorrenze.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Come hai intuito, sono avvallamenti del terreno, più o meno profondi, che la neve riempie formando dei depositi. Per questo in primavera sono le ultime zone dove la neve resiste (o le prime dove si ferma in inverno) e non a caso Levi precisa "sacche di neve fradicia". Proprio perché vi si affonda facilmente, sono molto fastidiose da attraversare per chi va in montagna.